# How to override the OnFormClosing event and exit the application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In my Visual Basic application, I have already once used this code

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        'Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Me.Hide()
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(450, "Su Enterprise", "The Application is in Background", ToolTipIcon.Info)
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub
```

It places the application in systemtray successfully but when I try to close it from taskbar by using this code

```
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

it cannot kill or exit the application as the previous OnFormClosing event triggered again.
Please help me to exit the application completely.

Answer (score 1):

Application.Current.Shutdown will do it if you're using WPF if you're using WinForms you can use Environment.Exit(0), which will do the same thing without the cleanup that WPF does.

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected... Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer if it answers your question, please?

Comment: @SubhajitMahato, do not use `Environment.Exit(0)`; it is the equivalent of using VB's [End Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement).  Instead, use [Application.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: This is a good explanation of the 3 methods and when you should use them.  And, yes, @TnTinMn is correct, if you're using WinForms you should use Application.Exit.  There may still be times when you need Environment.Exit(0) because something isn't stopping, but it's a last resort. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/applicationexit-vs-applicationshutdown-vs-environmentexit